# Call function in another function's call

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to call a function from inside the call of another function.

If I do it like this, it works fine. This returns 'x':

```
function returnval() {
    return ("x");
}

alert(
    returnval();
)
```

But how can I do the same thing while declaring the returnval function inside the function call? I've tried this, and everything else I could think of, to no avail. It returns 'function(){return("x");})' instead of the value itself, 'x':

```
alert(
    function() {
        return ("x");
    }
)
```

In a similar vein, I'd like to include if-statements in function calls as well. Is this at all possible?

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Really all you need is `()` after the closing `}` of the function. Additional parentheses around the function are not necessary, despite all the helpful answers :-)

Comment: @Pointy. Tell that to `SyntaxError`, I got, trying to execute function like you said.

Comment: Nope.  `alert(function() { return "Hi"; }());` is not a syntax error. Of course you do need the parentheses for the `alert()` function call; what I meant was that you don't need an **additional** layer of parentheses.

Comment: @Pointy Hmm, yes. In this case it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a thing, called like instant function call. You call a function just after a declaration:

```
(function() {
    // ... function body
})()
```

**upd** here it is: http://www.jspatterns.com/self-executing-functions/

Comment: Inside a function call you don't even need the extra parentheses, because the syntactic context makes the use of the `function` keyword unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`alert` is not *"the call of another function"*. You are passing a function as a parameter to a function. In the case of alert this will merely alert the function which in javascript is an object. You can however pass it the result of calling the function by doing as follows:

```
alert(
    function() {
        return ("x");
    }();
);
```

Comment: Hurrah for omitting the unnecessary (harmless) additional parentheses :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the function.  something like

```
alert(
    (function() {
        return ("x");
    })();
)
```

The `(function(){})()` construct is called a self-invoking function.

If you dont want to do that, you can do something like

```
var f = function() {
  return ("x");
};

alert(f());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (){
    alert('xxx');
}(); //alert('xxx');
```

so use it like this:

```
alert((function() {
        return ("x");
    })()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, meaning they can be assigned to variables, passed around and stored for later use.

The syntax you posted is passing the *function itself* to `alert`. What you want to do is invoke the function, and pass its return value to `alert`:

```
alert(
    (function() {
        return ("x");
    })() // Invoke the anonymous function
);
```